# Find all the concentric circles and fill them using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, contour, canny-operator

I have an image of concentric circles. Now I want to find some of them and fill the area between then with white color. I have done canny edge detection then erosion and area filter and got the below output.
I later on tried contouring but I am getting extra concentric circles.
Original image:[image]

Region to be extracted:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```cpp
        Mat cannyimg;
        Canny(histimg, cannyimg,35,65);
    
        Mat dilateimg;
        Mat kernel1 = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(2,2));
        dilate(cannyimg, dilateimg, kernel1, Point(-1, -1), 2);
    
        Mat imga = minareafilter(dilateimg, 500);
        
    
    
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        findContours(imga, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
        vector<Point2f>centers(contours.size());
        vector<float>radius(contours.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours_poly[i]);
            minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i], centers[i], radius[i]);
            
        }
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(imga.size(), CV_8UC3);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 256), rng.uniform(0, 256), rng.uniform(0, 256));
            if (radius[i] > 50 && radius[i] < 100) {
                //drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, (int)i, color);
                //rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2);
                circle(drawing, centers[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2);
            }
        }
```

My canny image is

[image]

After area filter the image is:

[image]

after contouring the image is:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the source image so we may try your code too

Comment: if you already have all the circle, I don't see what prevent you remove non-center ones?

Comment: @appleapple I don't know how to remove non-center circles?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I'll edit and attach the original image.

Comment: In the contour image, I only require the sky-blue color circle (outer circle) and the purple circle (inner circle) and want to remove all other circles.

Comment: To understand the problem totally: the required output you shared: what is the correspond of that white area in the input image ? You may show the desired area in the input image you want to detect

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I have added the image which signifies the area to be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems mostly based on detecting the contours efficiently. I tried the code which I have coded before to find the circles with an own method. You may check and try it [here](https://github.com/yunus-temurlenk/Opencv-Circle-Detection-Without-Houghcircle).

When I tried, I got the contours very clearly:

[image]

Then I tried to find the circles with same code and it found the circles and here is the result(I just rectangled the circles you need):

[image]

After detecting the circles, you need to design an algorithm for the desired circles. You may number their radius and choose the order accordingly. Here is your target output which I colorized with [fillConvexPolly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoQ5L3k158Y&t=229s). (I manually chose the circles here):

[image]

## Edit:

```
cv::fillConvexPoly(input, contour[outerId],cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
cv::fillConvexPoly(input,contour[innerrId],cv::Scalar(0,255,255));
```

Comment: Can you share the code, for filling the desired circles as you did to this image?

Comment: @KrupaliMistry Actually its just 2 lines of code. Since I ve deleted the code, I just added that 2 lines. I assume you already got the contours well. You need to find an algorithm to decide which contours should be chosen, and if you choose that 2 circle contours, you can easily apply the code above.

Comment: I got the two circles using different approach, and draw a circle too, but now I want to fill the red circle as you showed. I also know the radius for each circle. So, how to select the points as I only have two circles ?

Comment: Okey then the rest is easy. If you know all radius of circles. Order the circles from the biggest to smallest. Then choose the number 2 and number 5. At the end fill the circles.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just filtered out the circle based on the radius, Like the bigger circles were filled with white and the smaller circles were filled with black using contouring circles and thus got the required image.

Comment: Happy to hear that